# Clarification needed for the definition of Pushout and Pushout diagram from definition of Pullback and Pullback diagram

Tags: category-theory, notation, definition, pullback

The following is taken from $\textit{Categories}$ by Horst Schubert

Definition for Pullback

Let $f:A\rightarrow C, g:B\rightarrow C$ be two morhisms with the same codomain.  A $\textit{pullback}$ (also$\textit{cartesian square,}$ or $\textit{fibre product}$) for the pair $(f,g)$ is a commutative rectangle

$(1)$$\quad\quad$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} P & \xrightarrow{r} & B\\
\small {s}\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow\small {g}  &  \\
A & \xrightarrow{f} & C 
\end{array}$$\quad\quad$ $g\circ r=f\circ s$

with the following property:  if $u:D\rightarrow A, v:D\rightarrow B$ are morphisms with $f\circ u=g\circ v,$ then there is exactly one morphism $w:D\rightarrow P$ with $u=s\circ w$ and $v=r\circ w.$

Definition for Pushout

Let $f:A\rightarrow B, g:A\rightarrow C$ be two morphisms with the same domain. A $\textit{pushout}$ (also$\textit{cocartesian square,}$ $\textit{amagalmated sum,}$ or even $\textit{fibre sum,}$) for the pair $(f,g)$ is a commutative rectangle

$(2)$$\quad\quad$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} A & \xrightarrow{f} & B\\
\small {g}\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow\small {s}  &  \\
C & \xrightarrow{r} & Q 
\end{array}$$\quad\quad$ $s\circ f=r\circ g$

with the following property:  if $u:B\rightarrow X, v:C\rightarrow X$ are morphisms with $u\circ f=v\circ g,$ then there is exactly one morphism $w:Q\rightarrow X$ with $u=w\circ s$ and $v=w\circ r.$

For the definitions of Pullback and Pushout, I have two quick questions.
(1) For the case of Pullback, there is often the phrase "$s$ is a pullback of $g$ along $f$, $(s,r)$ is a pullback of $(f,g)$.  But for the case of pushout, is there a similar verbal description?  If so, would it be something along the line of $s$ is a pushout of $g$ along $r$?  or is it $s$ is a pushout of $g$ along $f$?

(2) How is the pushout diagram the dual of the pullback diagram.  I thought all I need to do to get the pushout diagram is to simply reverse all the arrows in the pullback diagram?  In many category theory text, when talking about the pushout diagram, all the book simply say is instruct the reader that the pushout is the dual of the pullback, and simply reverse all the arrows.  To me, the pushout diagram is more than just reversing the arrows of the pullback diagram.

Thank you in advance

Comment: For (2), you reverse all arrows in the category invvolved. Then the pushout condition in the original category is the same as the pullback condition in the dual category.

Comment: @MarcOlschok so to get pushout from (1), I do something like this:  $\quad\quad$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} P & \xleftarrow{r} & B\\
\small {s}\big\uparrow & & \big\uparrow\small {g}  &  \\
A & \xleftarrow{f} & C 
\end{array}$$\quad\quad$ $r\circ g=s\circ f \\$?  But is there the equivalent phrase "$g$ is apushback of $s$ along $f$, or $(g,r)$ is a pushback of $(f,,s)"?$

Comment: you could speak of e.g. $s$ as  the pushout of $g$ along $f$, but it is probably used less than in the pullback version. Popular special cases arise when $A$ is terminal and $g$ a monomorphism; then one could speak of "collapsing $C$".